# SignalR 2.x Error 500

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7.5, signalr, internal-server-error

I have deployed an Asp.Net MVC 4 application that is using SignalR v2.x on a server Windows 2008 R2 X64 and IIs 7.5. (.Net v4.5 is installed on the server and in IIS).
I'm constantly getting: Error 500 Internal Server error when I try to send the message from the client. 
I know this:
1. The message is received on the server side but the server does not respond and notify clients.
2.The firewall is disabled on the server
3.When i locally connect on the site (on the same machine that is deployed), SignalR works perfectly, but it does NOT work when I am connecting from another PC.

Please help!
Thanks

**UPDATE**
In event viewer there are no errors or warnings. But if I set customErrors to off then I got the following error:

`Server Error in '/' Application. A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. [SocketException (0x274c): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond {serverIP}:80]
   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +8794760
   System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception) +354

[AggregateException: One or more errors occurred.]
   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken) +14555717
   eLabin.Presentation.Web.Controllers.CommentController.NotifyHub(Post post) +343
   eLabin.Presentation.Web.Controllers.CommentController.PostComment(String comment, Guid predmetId) +300
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +225
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +248
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass39.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__33() +120
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49() +452
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20() +31
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +230
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +53
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +15
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +606
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288`

Comment: There are many things that can result in a 500 status code. By [looking at your server logs](http://blog.leansentry.com/2013/07/the-server-logs-you-need-to-know-to-fix-any-iis-aspnet-error/) and/or [temporarily disabling customErrors](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9678331/719967) you might be able to find more details about the 500. If those extra details don't help you resolve the issue yourself, you can add those details to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.
The problem was on the server side where I create HubConnection.

```
var url = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.IndexOf(Request.Url.AbsolutePath, StringComparison.InvariantCulture);
var connection = new HubConnection(url);
```

here the url was the external IP address of my server. So the server was trying to connect to itself through the external IP address.
All i did is change url to "localhost" and all worked fine.

```
var url = "localhost";
```